# How do I optimize the update query?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 2 fields:
PIN and fileName

I use a stored procedure to read a shared folder and populate the fileName field e.g. filexxx_PIN.pdf; I then use a cursor to run through the records and extract the PIN and update the record;

```
DECLARE @PIN AS VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @start INT , @length INT;
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR  SELECT FileName FROM [dbo].[pharmaCV];
SET @length = 11
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      SET @PIN = RTRIM(@name)
      SET @PIN = RIGHT(@PIN, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@PIN) + '_') - 1)
      SET @PIN = SUBSTRING (@PIN  , 0, @length ) 
      UPDATE pharmaCV SET PIN = @PIN WHERE FileName LIKE '%'+@PIN +'%'

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

This takes 25 seconds for 550 records;

Can anyone help with an UPDATE statement that does this?

Comment: *"How do I optimize the update query?"* Not using a `CURSOR` would be a big start. Why aren't you just doing this in a single `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: SQL is designed to work with sets not loops.  A CURSOR is a loop.  It is almost never correct to use a CURSOR when a select/query can be used.

Comment: `update` statement.  `set pin = SUBSTRING (RIGHT(RTRIM(FileName), CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(RTRIM(FileName)) + '_') - 1)  , 0, @length )` I didn't double check syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Normally We don't use Cursor for updating. I your case you can simply run below query

```
UPDATE [dbo].[pharmaCV]
    SET PIN = SUBSTRING (RIGHT(RTRIM(FileName), CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(RTRIM(FileName)) + '_') - 1)  , 0, 11 ) 
WHERE FileName LIKE '%'+SUBSTRING (RIGHT(RTRIM(@name), CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(RTRIM(@name)) + '_') - 1)  , 0, 11 ) +'%'
```